# Parameterized Query Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I'm having troubles with constructing query's in fat free framework with more than one parameter.

```
    $result = $db -> exec( array('SELECT * 
        FROM table WHERE table.type = ?', ' OR table.type = ?'), array($id[0],$id[1]));
```

I get this error : 
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

[Z:/web/SITE/lib/base.php:2015] Base->error(500,'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()')

The query works when I test it on the db directly, so that's not the issue.

And to be honest, I don't see any difference with the code shown [here](http://fatfreeframework.com/databases) :

```
$db->exec(
    array(
        'DELETE FROM diet WHERE food=:name',
        'INSERT INTO diet (food) VALUES (?)',
        'SELECT * FROM diet'
    ),
    array(
        array(':name'=>'cola'),
        array(1=>'carrot'),
        NULL
    )
);
```

EDIT Various options that don't work :

```
$result = $db -> exec( array('SELECT * 
            FROM table WHERE table.type = ? OR table.type = ?'), array($id[0],$id[1]));

$result = $db -> exec( array('SELECT * 
            FROM table WHERE table.type = ?', ' OR table.type = ?' ,$id[0],$id[1]);
```

This is the example from Fat free framework itself.. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Your second example has three different queries. The first one has one, somehow split into two parts. Replace it with something like   `$db->exec(  'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.type = ? OR table.type = ?', $id);`.

Comment: Parameters are ok,  remove array

Comment: I need the array since I don't know how much types my user will select. I can add OR's to the string in a loop, but I can't even make it work with hardcoded parameters.

@raina77ow, thanks. I didn't notice that at first, but in one string it doesn't work either. That was what I tested first..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
$result = $db -> exec(
  'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.type = ? OR table.type = ?', 
  array(1=>$id[0],2=>$id[1])
);
```

When the first parameter is an array, it'll transform into a transaction where each array value from $commands and $args is used for a single query. http://fatfreeframework.com/sql#Transaction

Comment: Still no luck "PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$result = $db->exec(
  'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.type = :typeOne OR table.type = :typeTwo', 
  array(':typeOne' => $id[0], ':typeTwo' => $id[1])
);
```

I had a problem with Fat Free and using `?` in sql. That solved my problems!